# Display image to take 80% of screen

Tags: android, android-layout

Using XML with relative layout as root layout , is there way that I can tell the image view to use 80% of screen and center it in the middle.

If I use wrap content or numeric dp then the image might be too small on big screens or too big for small screens. I want it to be 80‰ no matter what the screen looks like?

Please let me know how you would approach this thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use PercentRelativeLayout, import this

```
dependencies {
     ...
    compile 'com.android.support:percent:23.3.0'
    ...   
}
```

In XML, you use `<android.support.percent.PercentRelativeLayout>` instead `<RelativeLayout>`, it will support below code for those child

```
app:layout_heightPercent="80%"
app:layout_widthPercent="80%"
```

With android:layout_width/height, you can use "wrap_content", or without using, no problem.

Answer (score 0):

Well ,you can't do this on XML cause these mathematical operations can't be done there. You can just use MATCH_PARENT in the XML.

And then programmatically get the particular Views MeasuredWidth() and then set the width to be 80% of that.

Much easier and cleaner this way.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [PercentRelativeLayout](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/percent/PercentRelativeLayout.html)

```
<android.support.percent.PercentRelativeLayout
     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent">
 <ImageView
     app:layout_widthPercent="80%"
     app:layout_heightPercent="80%"
     android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>
 </android.support.percent.PercentFrameLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create using weight in linear layout like following

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="8"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="8">

                <ImageButton
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```